# Does map field runtime checking have an issue?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have simle code:

```
print('${map[segment].runtimeType}');
print(map[segment].runtimeType is List<dynamic>);
```

It outputs:

```
List<dynamic>
false
```

And I can't figure out why..

ps. `print(map[segment].runtimeType is List); // false`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with `map`.  You would get the same result with a simpler example:

```dart
int x;
print(x.runtimeType is int); // Prints: false
```

`x.runtimeType` is of type [`Type`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.5.1/dart-core/Type-class.html), which is *not* an `int` (nor a `List<dynamic>` in your example).

What you mean to do instead is to omit `.runtimeType` when doing type comparisons:

```dart
print(map[segment] is List<dynamic>);
```